# R dplyr group summarize and filter when ID exists in multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with ID, Category and amount with a few thousand records.

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c('V1', 'V1', 'V1', 'V3', 'V3', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5','V5','V5'),
  Category = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
  Amount   = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Using dplyr I want to group by ID and Category, sum the total amount per group, then filter the results to only have IDs which exist in multiple category.

result:

```
ID  Category Amount_Sum
V3  a        1
V3  b        2
V5  b        1
V5  c        2
```

I have the following code which groups and sums, but missing how to filter when the ID is in multiple groups

code:

```
x <- df1 %>% 
       group_by(ID, Category) %>% 
       summarize(CNT = n(), amount = sum(Amount)) %>% 
       filter(????????)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a combination of `length` and `unique` to `filter` as well:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Category) %>% 
  summarize(CNT = n(), amount = sum(Amount)) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(Category)) > 1)
```

**Output**

```
  ID    Category   CNT amount
  <chr> <chr>    <int>  <dbl>
1 V3    a            1      1
2 V3    b            2      2
3 V5    b            1      1
4 V5    c            2      2
```

Or here is a base R option using `aggregate` to do the summary, then using `ave` to do the filtering. Here, `Amount` is the variable that we want to apply 2 functions to (i.e., `length` and `sum`), but we want to do that for each group (`ID` and `Category`). `aggregate` will return a matrix with the results in 2 columns. So, to integrate those with the rest of the dataframe, we can use `do.call` to bind each of those columns to the dataframe. Then, we can rename the columns with the desired column names with `setNames`.

```
df1_output <-
  setNames(do.call(
    data.frame,
    aggregate(
      Amount ~ ID + Category,
      data = df1,
      FUN = function(x)
        c(CNT = length(x), amount = sum(x))
    )
  ), c(names(df1[1:2]), "CNT", "amount"))


df1_output[with(df1_output, ave(Category, ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1),]
```

Comment: could you provide more info or a link on your R base code. Specifically the "aggregate(Amount ~ ID + Category" part. It runs in my script, but I'm not sure what the input is doing for the parameter of that function. Thanks!

Comment: @Jorge Sure thing! I added a little more of explanation. Let me know if that makes sense or not (if not, then I'll try to reword).

Answer (score 3):

Using `n_distinct` on the `Category` should give you your desired result:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Category) %>% 
  summarize(CNT = n(), amount = sum(Amount)) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Category) > 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID    Category   CNT amount
  <chr> <chr>    <int>  <dbl>
1 V3    a            1      1
2 V3    b            2      2
3 V5    b            1      1
4 V5    c            2      2
```